# Git Lab configuration issue

Tags: gitlab

We have on premise GitLab. Is it possible to stop people from uploading all kinds of files eg. resist people from pushing in .exe files.

I've already looked at gitlabs apis, couldn't find anything relevant

Answer (score 2):

Yes can prohibit certain file names in the push rules, or could reduce the maximum file size to discourage people from uploading .exe files

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html

As @Iron Bishop pointed out this feature is not available in the free plan.

Alternatively, if you are so inclined, you could contribute a filter to the Gitlab code base and then use it. It should be fairly simple to add since the framework for filtering is already in place.

Comment here, if you need further help or want to explore the custom code option.

Cheers and all the best.

Comment: also notice that push rules are not available in the free plan

Comment: Thanks @systemkern, it'd be great if you could help me explore the custom code option.